# How does virtual machine anti-idle technology work?

Tags: shell, virtual-machine

I've used (as a end-user) virtual machines at two different companies now (one AWS, one in-house) where VMs are shut down if they are idle for some period of time. "Idle" seems to be defined by how long it's been since you issued a shell command. (If I'm only active in an X Windows app, the anti-idle trips.) I'm curious how this works -- does the relevant code really reside in the shell as it seems to? This would seem to be a vulnerability since anyone could appropriate and execute the relevant code to defeat the anti-idle feature. (It's also a bit annoying if you're working in an application and have no need of the shell.) I'm not trying (really!) to subvert anything, but I would like to understand things better so I can work with the behavior more productively.

Comment: Just to clarify, the entire VM (OS) shuts down, and not just your individual shell(s)?

Comment: Yep, the whole VM shuts down, run level 0